# HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError not creating hprof

Tags: java

My program throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

But when I added `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to the jvm parameters, but it seems that jvm didn't dump the heap, cause I never find any .hprof file. Why?

Answer (score 5):

See the section marked "Evaluation" at the bottom of this bug report.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6784422

The `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` will not trigger the dump when you cannot create a new native thread.

Answer (score 2):

Failure to create a thread isn't actually an out of memory condition; it's usually caused by a lack of native OS resources, not a lack of heap space.  A heap dump is probably not what you want in this situation... a stack dump of your current threads is likely to be far more useful.

Comment: Why is a stack dump more useful? What's the meaning of "native OS resources"? Could you explain more :)